# Switching AC or DC signal via TCP/IP

Tags: relay, trigger, tcp-ip

What is the cheapest/easiest way to switch an AC or DC signal of at least 10 V via TCP/IP?

I have 5 measurement devices which can be triggered over an 0-250 V AC/DC input (switching threshold 10 V). The devices are set up in different power plants which share a common computer network. 230 V AC is available.

For a power quality analysis (one day, about ten trigger signals) I have to trigger all of them more or less at the same time (up to 5 sec difference is acceptable) from my notebook or smartphone.

My idea would be some kind of IP-relay which can be switched over console or a web interface. Because of the different locations I'd need 5 of these devices (1 channel per device would be enough). An arduino or raspberry pi would probably do the job, but buying 5 of these and setting them up may be an overkill. Is there a cheaper device for my one time application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Industrial solution is modbus tcp/ip protocol. I doubt that you will find any cheaper board than Arduino, anyway if you find a board with ethernet then you might look if ther exists a ready made protocol stack for modbus tcp/ip for that platform.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is cheaper than the Arduino with Ethernet.

Comment: Then find a suitable modbus tcp client stack. You can also try Codesys demo, it will turn your RasPi into a industrial PLC like system. Unfortunately it works only for 2 hours in demo mode, 35 eur for licence for full time. Anyway I would try to find an opensource variant

Comment: Just a little search and I have found a simple industrial solution, http://program-plc.blogspot.si/2015/05/scada-modbus-tcp-and-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: This one looks interesting. Triggering all five units from the same scada button should be feasible?

Comment: I had never used that scada, but usually they are made to link a specific tag, or to execute a macro, where multiple actions can be acheived. It also depends on your knowledge, for example if you know a certain programming language/software you can get a modbus tcp client, while server is needed on the raspi.

Answer (score 0):

There are readymade IP enabled power strips in approximately the same price range as a selfmade solution using an Arduino or Raspberry Pi would end up in total.

Comment: And the ready-made ones are UL-approved, which might matter for insurance purposes, etc.

Comment: I prefer a readymade solution like such a power strip. A difficulty I see here is to switch all of them fast enough. A good webinterface (switching all 5 signals from the same site would be great) or support for scripting is crucial.